# how to fill the value in table through web driver?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

In one of my application there is one table and 50 rows in it. now there is 50 different id for the all the table rows. my scenario is to fill the table row through the wen driver. so how can i perform this task ?

Comment: Please give us more details. What do you want the table to be filled with? and what have you tried so far?

Comment: please, provide code of your table

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know we cant modify DOM via WebDriver, but you can do it using JavascriptExecutor

try this:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
WebEelement tableCells = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("table > tr > td"));

for (WebElement cell : tableCells) {
    String randString = getRandomString(20);
    js.executeScript("text('"+ randString +"')", cell);
}

private static String getRandomString(final int length) {
    char[] chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890".toCharArray();
    Random random = new Random(); 
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        char c = chars[random.nextInt(chars.length)];
        sb.append(c);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```